# about smart card installation

Tags: linux, smartcard

```
while configh the smart card getting below error








 checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
```

checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... no
checking for sys/types.h... no
checking for sys/stat.h... no
checking for stdlib.h... no
checking for string.h... no
checking for memory.h... no
checking for strings.h... no
checking for inttypes.h... no
checking for stdint.h... no
checking for unistd.h... no
checking ifdhandler.h usability... no
checking ifdhandler.h presence... no
checking for ifdhandler.h... no
configure: error: ifdhandler.h not found, install pcsc-lite 1.3.3 or later, or use ./configure PCSC_CFLAGS=...

Comment: Installing the proper Debian package.

Answer (score 5):

Try installing libpcsclite-dev package (tried on Karmic).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have any header files.  It's unlikely you have `gcc` installed correctly, either.  Try installing `gcc`, `glibc`, etc.  I don't know which distro you're using, but in Ubuntu, there is a package called `build-essential` that installs everything you need to compile source packages.

Alternatively, try to find a binary package for your distro.